# Can we play audio through Javascript coding even if Internet Explorer browser disables audio in settings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, internet-explorer-11

I need help with **JavaScript** coding like, even when I disable "**Play sound in web pages**" in Internet Explorer settings, I need to play the audio in my web page. Is there any way to make that possible ? Am using Internet explorer version 11 ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you disable "Play sound in web pages" in Internet explorer you turn off the ability to play sound through HTML5 'audio' controls.

You can always use Flash based flash player that will ignore this option.

There are many completer solution for the widest support possible.

[Plugin with fallback](http://mediaelementjs.com/)

**Or if you want to do it yourself**

[How to user html5 with fallback](http://matt.coneybeare.me/getting-html5-audio-tag-and-flash-fallback-to/)